# Is the "Cellar" folder only used for Homebrew?

Tags: macos, homebrew

Is the "Cellar" folder only used for Homebrew? If I am *not* using Homebrew, I can safely remove it?

Answer (score 29):

The script for uninstalling Homebrew removes it completely, so it's probably safe to remove it.

https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/FAQ

> #### How do I uninstall Homebrew?
>
> If you installed to `/usr/local` then you can use the script in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/1173223) to uninstall — it will only remove Homebrew and the stuff Homebrew installed leaving anything else in /usr/local alone.
>
> Provided you haven’t put anything else in Homebrew’s prefix (`brew --prefix`), you can generally just `rm -rf` that directory. This is because Homebrew won’t touch files outside its prefix.

Comment: From one of the comments, I was hesitated...The FAQ says that this gist uninstalls ONLY the homebrew stuff.
The FAQ says that Cellar is the place to install non-homebrew stuff.
This gist removes Cellar.

Comment: @Yoga If you look closely, the FAQ says "it will only remove Homebrew **and the stuff Homebrew installed**". The homebrew homepage says "Homebrew installs packages to their own directory and then symlinks their files into /usr/local." Check this [useful article](http://hivelogic.com/articles/using_usr_local/) about using `usr/local` by Dan Benjamin of 5by5.

Comment: @myhd - that article is not that useful - FHS is Linux and not Unix, /usr/local is for stuff you compiled yourslef but many unicies also have /opt (as also does Macports) and other directories that are not affected by system installs

Comment: Still, it is very common for `./configure` with no `--prefix=` argument to just assume you want to install in /usr/local; and the Homebrew FAQ does suggest installing stuff you've compiled yourself there, and then using `brew link` on it.

Comment: To clarify: The "Cellar" directory is a location that Homebrew made up for its own use. (The name fits with Homebrew's "beer" theme: the "cellar" is where you store your "kegs" of "homebrew".) No other software uses it. So if you don't need Homebrew *and the programs you installed using Homebrew*, you can delete Cellar. @myhd - when homebrew says "to their own directory", that "own directory" is located under "Cellar".

Comment: @myhd Thanks for Dan Benjamin article link! Just what I need to understand the differences btw usr/bin and usr/local.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. You can remove Cellar directory.

Answer (score 5):

According to its [installation instructions](https://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/howto-macosx-install.html), [Java Service Wrapper](https://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/home.html) is also using a Cellar directory:

```
/opt/local/Cellar/wrapper
```

but it is distinct from the Homebrew Cellar which is in

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar
```

for Apple Silicon mac and

```
/usr/local/Cellar
```

for Intel mac.